# How Do I Implement ListView in AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, listview

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

   if (currentUser != null){
       //show user the homepage
       ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Status");
       query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
       @Override
       public void done(List<ParseObject> status, ParseException e) {
       if (e==null){
           //success
           mStatus = status;

            StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(getListView().getContext(), mStatus);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
        //ther was a problem.
        }
      }
    });

    } else {
        //show login screen
        Intent takeUserToLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(takeUserToLogin);
    }
}
```

In above code I got error on `getListView()` and `setListAdapter`.

I have the following code in `StatusAdapter` class:

```java
public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {

    protected Context mContext;
    protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;

    public StatusAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> status){
        super(context, R.layout.homepagecustomlayout, status);
        mContext = context;
        mStatus = status;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.homepagecustomlayout,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.usernameHomepage = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernameHP);
            holder.statusHomepage = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusHP);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ParseObject statusObject = mStatus.get(position);

        //user
        String username = statusObject.getString("user");
        holder.usernameHomepage.setText(username);

        //status
        String status = statusObject.getString("newStatus");
        holder.statusHomepage.setText(status);

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        TextView usernameHomepage;
        TextView statusHomepage;
    }
}
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuZF3iZYONo&index=15&list=PL1LLSQc9OcKkerhxJd1q34ZYt4HfjvWrk).

Answer (score 4):

`getListView()` and `setListAdapter()` are methods of `ListActivity`/`ListFragment`.

But, it seems like you are extending `AppCompatActivity`. So, you can add a `listView` to your `activity_main`; and then:

```
ListView listview = findViewById(R.id.yourlistID);
```

whereby you set the adapter this way - `listView.setAdapter();`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

### A Few Key Changes You Need To Make.

I had the same issues when switching from `ListView` to `AppCompatActivity`. There are few changes that you need to make to replace what `ListView` had built-in. I have listed them out here to ease your migration.

1. You can no longer call `this` to get the `ListView`. You need to fetch it from the view. I recommend creating a method like this:

   ```
   protected ListView getListView() { return findViewById( android.R.id.list ); }
   ```

   *NOTE: If you list doesn't have an `id` of `list`, you will need to update it, but I recommend using the id `list`, if possible because it keeps it consistent and means you can use this method on more than one Activity.*
2. You can no longer just override the `onListItemClick` method because it doesn't exist on `AppCompatActivity` so you'll need to create your own listener and set it to the list with `setOnItemClickListerner` and add it to your `onCreate`. Here's an example:

   ```
   getListView().setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) { 
       Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition( position );

       String itemId = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "id" ) );

       Intent itemActivityIntent = new Intent( view.getContext(), Item.class );

       itemActivityIntent.putExtra( view.getContext().getPackageName() + ".itemId",  itemId );

       startActivity( itemActivityIntent);
     } ) 
   } );
   ```
3. You can no longer call `this.setListAdapter` in `populateListView`. Instead, you will need to fetch the ListView and call `setAdapter`, like this:

   ```
   getListView().setAdapter( adapter );
   ```

That should do it. There might be some other tweaks you need to make for your setup but those are big ones.